# Automate GKE Node migration using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am using terraform to provision gke clusters. Currently if we have to modify the node pool properties we do it manually (*create new nodepool, cordon old nodepool, drain nodes*).

Is there a way i can automate it using terraform itself? currently if i change any properties it destroys and recreates the entire node.

Comment: If the API forces a recreate on node property modification, then there is not really a workaround here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the

```
lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
```

in terraform so it will create the Node pool first and then stop the old instance or node pool.

Read more about it : https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle

Comment: Thanks. I also want to cordon and drain the old Node to have zero downtime. So tried to use this module https://github.com/baozuo/terraform-google-gke-node-pool. Only issue is that the `node_pool_provisioner` block runs before the `google_container_node_pool` though there is a depends_on.

Comment: is it before or after ? i think depends on so `google_container_node_pool` will be getting executed and thn `node_pool_provisioner`.

Comment: it null resource so you can also copy that block and use it, with the module however you might need script folder that is getting executed nothing much. it's more like it's running command from local env `local-exec` and drain the node. you edit this script and run it also for cordon and drain nodes as per need https://github.com/baozuo/terraform-google-gke-node-pool/blob/master/scripts/drain-nodes.sh

Comment: it supposed to run `google_container_node_pool` before `node_pool_provisioner` due to depends on but it always runs `node_pool_provisioner` first. This affects the evicted pods without any nodes until new node is created

Comment: yes right got your issue, but you can use that script and change it so first will cordon node and drain after that, either you can write multiple steps to run `local-exec` separate scripts instead single.