# GKE Node Pool Update via Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, upgrade

Is there a way to change the machine type of a node pool through terraform in a rolling fashion? The recommended way to change the machine type of a node pool from what I'm reading is to create a new node pool with the new machine type, migrate the workloads to it, then delete the old node pool.

However, we're using terraform to manage our clusters and node pools so if I change the machine type of a node pool in my terraform code, all terraform knows how to do is delete the existing node pool and create a new one with the new machine type. Node pools have specific names and my terraform code expects only that name.

There must be a way to allow terraform to support this?

Thanks!

Edit: I did some more research on this and I don't believe it's possible. Instead, I opted to just manage two node pools in my terraform code which I can toggle on/off and float workloads between them when node pool upgrades are required.

Comment: any update on this ? please feel free to update the status of question if resolves your issues.

Answer (score 3):

As the update is the best solution to go with, Edit the **TF** with **two** **node** **pools** and initially running both.

Once the **second** node pool is available you can **Cordon** the Nodes in Node pool and then start **draining** so all workload running on **Node pool 1** will get shifted to **Node pool 2**.

> What is terraform is not supporting **Cordon** & **Drain** option ?

You can use the **local-exec** with **kubectl**

Ref shell script & TF module : https://github.com/baozuo/terraform-google-gke-node-pool/blob/master/scripts/drain-nodes.sh

Here you can refer my another answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72726139/5525824

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up with an answer...what I was trying to do isn't possible. I opted to go the route of just managing two separate node pools in terraform and toggling them on and off when upgrades are required. Terraform isn't smart enough to know how to "upgrade" a node pool without destroying and then recreating.